# Android Web-view Error Your Browser is not compatible?

Tags: android, webview

This is my webview I am getting error like Your Browser  is not compatible

for my Url Its says currently,the iClient Supports Chrome,Safari,Firefox and IE 10+

This is my Webview

```
public class MyWebV extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_data);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Iid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        did = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences(MyWebV_SP, 0);
        HashMap<String, String> map= (HashMap<String, String>) s.getAll();

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web5);
        WebSettings set = webView.getSettings();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        set.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MyWebV.this, "Please Wait", "Loading...");
        webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                String summary = "<html><body style='background:#fff;'><br><div ><b><p style='color: black;font-size:20px;text-align:left;'>Unable to load information.</p></b><div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Please check if your Network connection.</div><br><div> <p style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Or<br><br> <div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Server May be Temporarily Down\n" + "\n" +
                        "<div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Please Try After Sometime</p></div></div></div></div></body></html>";
                view.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressBar == null) {

                    progressBar.setTitle("Please Wait !");
                    progressBar.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressBar.show();
                }
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                try{
                    if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                        progressBar.dismiss();

                    }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                String summary = "<html><body style='background:#fff;'><br><div ><b><p style='color: black;font-size:20px;text-align:left;'>Unable to load information.</p></b><div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Please check your Network Connection.</div><br><div> <p style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Or<br><div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Server May be Temporarily Down\n" + "\n" +
                        "<div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Please Try After Sometime</p></div></div></div></div></body></html>";
                view.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        String url = "https://iclientsimulator.test.tyro.com/configuration.html#landing";
        System.out.println(url);

        try{

            if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
            else{
                String e = "<html><body style='background:#fff;'><br><div ><b><p style='color: black;font-size:20px;text-align:left;'>Please Exit app and Open it After setup.</p></b></div></div></body></html>";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            String summary = "<html><body style='background:#fff;'><br><div ><b><p style='color: black;font-size:20px;text-align:left;'>Unable to load information.</p></b><div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Server May be Temporarily Down\n" + "\n" +
                    "<div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Please Try After Sometime</p></div></div></body></html>";
        }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    webView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void startWebView(String url) {

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyWebV.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Here I am using `WebChromeClient` But I am getting error form that url that you browser is not compatible

this is the Url https://iclient.tyro.com/configuration.html#landing I am trying to reach in my web-view...

How ever its loading on any mobile browser not only chrome default browser... Can any one suggest me Its just a part of my web-view to confirm devices of that tyro....

Comment: This problem started happening to me one week ago out of the blue, only on Galaxy S8 devices!